# How to capture image automatically using intent and without any user interaction

Tags: android, android-camera-intent

I am trying to develop an android application that automatically takes picture using camera intent without any interaction from a user but cannot get the code to trigger the image capturing action automatically. anybody with help??. Here is my code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    pictureButton = findViewById(R.id.captureFront);
    countDownTimer = new MyCountDownTimer(startTime, interval);

    if (!timerHasStarted) {
        countDownTimer.start();
        timerHasStarted = true;

    } else {
        countDownTimer.cancel();
        timerHasStarted = false;
        // startB.setText("RESTART");
    }

}

public void pictureCapture() throws IOException {
    pictureButton.setEnabled(true);
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    File sampleDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    try {
        imagefile = File.createTempFile("image", ".jpeg", sampleDir);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "sdcard access error");
        return;
    }
    takePicture(shutter, raw, postview, jpeg);

    startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);

}

public final void takePicture(Camera.ShutterCallback shutter,
        Camera.PictureCallback raw, Camera.PictureCallback postview,
        Camera.PictureCallback jpeg) {

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Image captured and saved to fileUri specified in the Intent
            Toast.makeText(this, "Image saved to:\n" + data.getData(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // User cancelled the image capture
            Toast.makeText(this, "Image cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        } else {
            // Image capture failed, advise user
            Toast.makeText(this, "Image failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public class MyCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer {
    public MyCountDownTimer(long startTime, long interval) {
        super(startTime, interval);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        // text.setText("Time's up!, finishes");
        countDownTimer.cancel();
        try {
            pictureCapture();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        // text.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
    }

}
```

};

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it using Camera Api.

[Camera API in Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html)

No need to do any UI for capturing then Image just call the camera api using service or any background thread or as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this...

```
mPreview.getCamera().autoFocus(autoFocusCallback);

Camera.AutoFocusCallback autoFocusCallback = new Camera.AutoFocusCallback() {
    public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) {   

        mPreview.getCamera().takePicture(shutterCallback, null,  jpegCallback); 
    }
};
```

So you'd just call `autoFocus` to get the ball rolling on the photo taking process.

Comment: this is good one ....but can you tell me that a developer can have a control over event of capturing image ,is it possible?

Comment: @YogeshSeralia, I'm sorry, I don't understand the question.

Comment: i wanna ask you that when I open any camera app , then it asks for user to click on button to capture the image, but is it possible that we can control the capturing event with selfie stick?

Comment: As my answer says, you can take a picture at any time based on whatever condition you wish. A user's input is not needed.